# Правильное использование dispatch_async

Tags: ios, swift

Потихоньку изучаю `Swift` и возник вопрос, когда правильно использовать `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {...})`. К вопросу привело странное поведение `UIAlerController`. Иногда когда его вызываю, пишет, что мол не на главной `thread` и впоследствии приведёт к `weird crashes`. Илии когда программно закрываю, пишет, что мол не может закрыть пока что-то `dismissing`. Вычитала, что необходимо использовать `dispatch_async`, вроде помогло, но как правильно? Во всех случаях в нем вызывать/закрывать? И вообще какие действия и в каких случаях лучше писать в `dispatch_async`?

Answer (score 2):

1. Весь UI нужно обновлять только из главного потока
2. Этот код обновит UI, но будет ждать завершения операции. Так лучше не делать.

   ```
   dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // Update the UI on the main thread.
   });
   ```
3. А этот правильный код обновит UI, но не затормозит текущий поток

   ```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // Update UI
   });
   ```

Comment: А как узнать, точно я обновляю из главного потока или оно не в главном потоке и нужно приписать dispatch_async?

Comment: @Son'kaV чтобы узнать, выполняется ли текущий код в главном потоке, можно использовать ***NSThread.currentThread().isMainThread***